# pass a string value as a parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

I used crystal report to generate a report.Now I want to save print details in PrintHistory table when a user generates a report. I am getting details of the user and system details using a token. I want to pass token value to my stored procedure without using it in the report.

Here is my code for the report generation,

```
case "OutletToOutletInventryTransferService":

                        object transferCode = Request.Form["transferId"];
                        object issuedBy = Request.Form["curentUser"];
                        object tockenNum = Request.Form["tocken"];

                       string transferId = Convert.ToString(transferCode);
                       string curentUser = Convert.ToString(issuedBy);
                       string tocken = Convert.ToString(tockenNum);

                        myReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/MIS/OutletToOutletInventryTransferService/OutletToOutletTransfer.rpt"));
                        reportTytle = "Outlet To Outlet Inventory Transfer";
                        myReport.SetParameterValue("@TransferCode", transferId);
                        myReport.SetParameterValue("@UserName", curentUser);
                        //myReport.SetParameterValue("@Tocken", tocken);

                        break;
```

Here is my stored procedure,

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PrintOutlettoOutletTransfer]  --exec PrintOutlettoOutletTransfer 'INTRANSYS000044'
    @TransferCode varchar(20),
    @token varchar(100)

    AS
    BEGIN

DECLARE @Isprint AS int
DECLARE @user AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PcIp AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PcName AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @AditUserName AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @outlet AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ServerName AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @user = ''


-- Retrive data from user login history from Tocken
SELECT 
@user = UserLogInHistory.UserId,
@PcIp = LogInIp, 
@outlet=OutletCode,
@ServerName = ServerId,
@AditUserName = Users.UserFullName
from UserLogInHistory
inner join Users on Users.UserId = UserLogInHistory.UserId
where UserTokenId = @token;

    SELECT
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode,'') AS 'TransferId',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TransferDate,'') AS 'TransferDate',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode,'') AS 'ItemCode',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.ItemDescription,'') AS 'ItemDescription',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.Qty,'') AS 'Qty',

    STUFF((SELECT  InventoryTransferSerials.SerialNo +' / ' 
           FROM InventoryTransferSerials
           WHERE InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode = InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode
           AND InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode 
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS 'SN',

    ISNULL(InventoryStatus.Description,'') AS 'InventoryStatus',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.FromOutlet,'') AS 'outletFrom' ,
    ISNULL(F.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TOOutlet,'') AS 'outletTO' ,
    ISNULL(T.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets' 

    FROM    InventoryTransferHeader
    INNER JOIN
    Outlets F ON InventoryTransferHeader.FromOutlet = F.OutletCode
    INNER JOIN
    Outlets T ON InventoryTransferHeader.ToOutlet = T.OutletCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryStatus on InventoryStatus.StatusCode = InventoryTransferHeader.InventoryStatus
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryTransferLine ON InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode = InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode 
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN
    --InventoryTransferSerials ON InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode 
    --AND InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode = InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode


    WHERE (InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode = @TransferCode OR @TransferCode = '') AND (InventoryStatus.StatusCode = 1 OR InventoryStatus.StatusCode = 2)

    --- Insert Values to Audit table
INSERT INTO PrintHistory
([DocType],[Reference],[AuditOutlet],[AuditUser],[AuditDate],[AuditType],[AuditIp],[AuditPc],[AuditUserName])
values
('OutletToOutletInventryTransfer',@TransferCode,@outlet,@user,GETDATE(),'1',@PcIp,@ServerName,@AditUserName);


      UPDATE InventoryTransferHeader
      SET   InventoryTransferHeader.[Print] = 1,
            InventoryTransferHeader.[PrintUser] = @user,
            InventoryTransferHeader.[PrintDate] = GETDATE()
      WHERE InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode = @TransferCode AND InventoryTransferHeader.[Print] = 0;
    END
```

How can i pass the token value to the stored procedure?

Comment: Where's the select query

Comment: where do you want to pass your token?

Comment: seem like your token is fine here from UserLogInHistory
inner join Users on Users.UserId = UserLogInHistory.UserId
where UserTokenId = @token;

Comment: can i use sqlCommand to pass the token?

Comment: my print history table is not getting updated. I don't know why? I think it because not passing data to the SP.Can anyone help please.